# what happens when an web server control on an .aspx file is redefined in the code behind?

Tags: asp.net

```
Mark Up:
<asp:Label ID="Status" runat="server" Visible="false" />

Code Behind:

public partial class Files : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label Status;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Status.
        }
    }
```

Now whenever I tried to use the label *Status* in the Page_Load handler I was warned as *this member is defined more than once*. My question is why I was not warned while redifining it as an instance member ? and actually is it possible to proceed with the control ?

Comment: With this markup, your Label declaration should appear in the designer.cs file, you don't have to declare it again.

Comment: @Paciv designer.cs file is generated in the case of an web application project. what will be the case when working with an website project ?

Comment: I just looked up, and yes, Web site project doesn't generate designer.cs files. Although the label should already be declared and you don't have to do it again. If you can't find the Label variable without declaring it again, it must be because the link between your markup and code-behind file is broken. Either you've changed the namespace or the location. You should check to see if the `inherits` property of the markup file (.aspx) still target your code-behind.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880323/no-default-aspx-designer-cs-files-in-my-asp-net-project

Answer (score 0):

You do not need this line:

```
protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label Status;
```

because when you declare a control in ASP.net layout it is automatically created as a field of  your page class.

Answer (score 0):

You have already used the `Label Object` Status in Designer. Can you check the designer .cs class for it's declaration? A variable with the same name can not be declared twice.

Corrected code is below...

### Mark Up:

```
<asp:Label ID="Status" runat="server" Visible="false" />
```

### Code Behind:

```
public partial class Files : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Pseudo Code
            //Status.PropertyName....
        }
}
```